# Supervised classification in parts

Tags: classification, erdas-imagine, subset

I have an image from 1990 (res 30m, also clouds) for an area equal 2100km2 and when I performed the supervised classification, the software (ERDAS) confuses the classes that look similar. Is it possible to perform the classification in parts but to get only one result? and how? I believe, if I divide the image into two or three parts, the classification will yield better results.